# Трансляция реальных ip адресов внутрь docker контейнера

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apache2, docker

Такая структура на моем сервере (ubuntu14.04), там установлен nginx в качестве фронденда, который проксирует запросы внутрь докер контейнера.

Его config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 256M;
        server_name example.com;
        #ssl on;
        #ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.crt;
        #ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.key;

        #ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        #ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        #ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

   location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32774/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

В докер контейнере установлен апач
Его config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dir_site 


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Также установлен модуль apache mod_rpaf, и его config:

```
<IfModule rpaf_module>
    RPAFenable On
    RPAFsethostname On
    RPAFproxy_ips 172.17.0.8
    RPAFheader X-Real-IP
</IfModule>
```

ifconfig из докера:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:08  
      inet addr:172.17.0.8  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:8/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:125968 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:69301 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:82479961 (82.4 MB)  TX bytes:109421668 (109.4 MB)
```

Проблема в том что в логах апача все пользователи имеют ip 172.17.42.1

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что этот сайт предназначен для общения на русском языке.

Comment: Хотел запостить на майн сайт а получилось тут, уж извните пожалуйста, исправил на русский.

Comment: Я бы сильно не рекомендовал вам биндиться на автоматом выдаваемые айпишники/порты. Либо service discovery, либо линкинг и статичные порты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**актуально**

в настройках *rpaf* в `RPAFproxy_ips` надо добавить *ip-адрес* контейнера (в данном случае — `172.17.42.1`).

---

**неактуально**

попробуйте в *location-е* заменить значения для `X-Forwarded-For`:

```
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
```

ещё, возможно, стоит попробовать закомментировать строку про `X-Real-IP` в том же *location-е* и `RPAFheader X-Real-IP` в конфигурации *rpaf*.

по крайней мере у меня на серверах такая настройка (правда, без *docker-а*, но это, по-моему, несущественно в данном случае).

---

неплохо было бы посмотреть на переменные окружения, которые получаете *apache*, на предмет внешнего *ip-адреса*. если *apache* работает в связке с *php*, то можно запросить извне *php-файл* примерно такого содержания:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: К сожалению, видимо докер тут принципиальное значение имеет. Сделал все как советовали, но воз и ныне там. Благодарю за ответ. Может кто-нибудь имел практику работы с nginx+docker+apache = realip

Comment: посмотрите переменные окружения, которые получает *apache* . если там есть *php*, то можно запросить извне мини-файл `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Comment: `<IfModule rpaf_module>
    RPAFenable On
    RPAFsethostname On
    RPAFproxy_ips 172.17.42.1
   #RPAFheader X-Real-IP
</IfModule>`

Comment: поищите вообще внешний ip-адрес: может быть, он где-то в другой переменной фигурирует.

Comment: все заработало, в настройках модуля ставим ип адрес докер контейнера который видим извне докера с самого сервера. Все настройки можно оставить как были изначально, но все равно большое вам спасибо!

Comment: обновил ответ, проверьте, пожалуйста, всё ли верно.